# Check if a dropdown element exists querySelector?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I've been using

```
    var name= (document.querySelector('input#element') ? document.querySelector('input#element').value : '');
```

to check if a form contains a particular element and return the value if TRUE. It's working fine for text boxes, but not for dropdowns. Can querySelector() be used in this manner for dropdowns?

Note: I don't care about whether a particular option exists in the list, which is what most answers I've found are addressing. I simply want to know if the field is on the form.

Answer (score 0):

> It's working fine for text boxes, but not for dropdowns.

If you are using the same selector for dropdown then it should not be `input#element`. Try `select#element`

but actually `#element` is enough for both situations. Prefer it:

```
var element = document.querySelector('#element')
var name = element ? element.value : ''
```